# help page format issue: revisionGuid

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=revisions/{id}/{revisionguid}

`revisionGuid` is inconsistent.

`revisionguid` seems appropriate (and will remove one special case from my api parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter naming has been made consistent.